# Android: AsyncTask behaving weird in onCreate

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm executing the practically identical code (besides the return statement) in `onCreate()` in two different ways:

- once in a Thread (that works)
- and once in an AsyncTask

Somehow the Exception thrown in the AsyncTask can't even be debugged... do you have an idea why this code doesn't work in the AsyncTask and why I can't debug de Exception? (It is not present as a variable)

```
public class TrainingProgressActivity extends ActivityTemplate {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_training_progress);        

        // the not working AsyncTask variant
        new ProgressGetterTask().execute("");

        // the working Thread variant
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                RestTemplate restTemplate = RestTemplateFactory.createRestTemplate();
                FeatureSetCollectionProgress i = restTemplate.postForObject(URLHelper.BASE_PATH+"training/progress", getDevice(), FeatureSetCollectionProgress.class);
                System.out.println(i.getMobilityProgress().get(0).getTransportationMeanType().toString());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ex");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}).start();
    }

    /**
     * ProgressGetterTask. (not working ???)
     */
    private class ProgressGetterTask extends AsyncTask<String, FeatureSetCollectionProgress, FeatureSetCollectionProgress> {

        protected FeatureSetCollectionProgress doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                RestTemplate restTemplate = RestTemplateFactory.createRestTemplate();
                return restTemplate.postForObject(URLHelper.BASE_PATH+"training/progress", getDevice(), FeatureSetCollectionProgress.class);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null; // setting breakpoint here, 'e' cannot be resolved to a variable.
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(FeatureSetCollectionProgress featureSetCollectionProgress) {
            if(featureSetCollectionProgress!=null) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried default `e.printStackTrace()` before `return null;` to see if error exists and is not null? I'd suspect you are using debugger wrong.

Comment: and it burns in NPE on non-initialized `e` variable?

Comment: why don't you add e.printStackTrace() before returning null?

Comment: sadly that doesn't help.